# Given integral equation, find $y(1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, integral-equations

- Let $\operatorname{y}\left(t\right)$ be a continuous function on $\left[0,\infty\right)$  whose Laplace transforms exists. If $\operatorname{y}\left(t\right)$ satisfies
  \begin{equation}
  \int_{0}^{t}\left[1 - \cos\left(t - \tau\right)\right]
  \operatorname{y}\left(\tau\right)
  \,\mathrm{d}\tau = t^{4}\label{1}\tag{1}
  \end{equation}
  then $\operatorname{y}\left(1\right) = $
- I was able to find the answer by differentiating
  ( Leibniz integration
  $\mbox{rule )}\left(\ref{1}\right)$ twice to get
  $$
  \int_{0}^{t}\cos\left(t - \tau\right)
  \operatorname{y}\left(\tau\right)
  \,\mathrm{d}\tau = 12t^{2}\,,
  $$
  and subtracting with original equation and differentiating again to get $\operatorname{y}\left(t\right) = 4t^{3} + 24t^{2}$ and hence $\operatorname{y}\left(1\right) = 28$.

One's allowed only less than a minute per question in the exam, and that makes me doubt if there's a simpler way to do it $!$.

Is there a simpler way to do it $?$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laplace transform of the convolution of two functions is the product of the Laplace transforms of the functions.  Thus, take the LT of both sides:

Let

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, y(t) e^{-s t} = Y(s)$$
$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, (1-\cos{t}) e^{-s t} = \frac1{s} - \frac{s}{1+s^2} = \frac1{s(1+s^2)}$$

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, t^4 e^{-s t} = \frac{4!}{s^5} $$

Thus,

$$\frac{Y(s)}{s(1+s^2)} = \frac{24}{s^5} \implies Y(s) = 24 \left (\frac1{s^2} + \frac1{s^4} \right )$$

We can invert this LT very easily to recover $y(t)$.  It is

$$y(t) = 24 t + 4 t^3$$

and $y(1)=\cdots$

Comment: I did study basics of Laplace transforms few years back, I did not understand it's use then, hence left it as it is! I think I should reread my notes! Thank you!